# Parser error after importing a symfony project in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, parse-error

I got an error after importing a symfony project in Eclipse. Please refer to the attached.[image]

The error message is: Parser error "';' expected after expression (Found token: Identifier(Symfony))"

This project was import from my computer, and I got it by git. I'm a newbie to PHP Symfony project. Can you please help me out?

Comment: This issue doesn't matter for your application. It's looks like bug in Eclipse. Please update your IDE to current version.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- I pasted the error message, here is: Parser error "';' expected after expression (Found token: Identifier(Symfony))"   -------However, you can drag this picture to a new tab, it would show ALL the details.

Comment: Check your settings, more to the point: the PHP version. Make sure its >=5.3, if not namespaces won't be recognized. Did you run `php composer.phar install`, _without_ the composer.lock file?

Comment: @NHG I checked my eclipse, it's the latest version. However, I don't get any error if I create a new Symfony project. Did you experience this? Is there something like class_path I need to configure?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I checked PHP version, it's PHP 5.5.0. Can you please let me know the steps of checking/setting this environment of this project? When I create a new Symfony project, I didn't get this error.

Comment: @53iScott: I'm not psychic, so I don't know your project. Generally, if it's a git clone, you might want to delete composer.lock, then run `composer.phar install` register your bundles and install your web-dir stuff... I don't know how you imported this project, so I can't really pin-point the issue. I can tell you that I ditched eclipse and started using netbeans because symfony projects and eclipse are just a pain...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem "I can tell you that I ditched eclipse and started using netbeans because symfony projects and eclipse are just a pain" -- I'm sure these words helped me a lot! I'm switching to Netbeans now, although the UI of Eclipse is much better. Thanks so much!